# Get indexPath from custom Tableview section header

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have created a custom View and added it to the tableView section header.

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        if section == 2 {

            if (headerView == nil) {
                headerView = CustomHeaderSection(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.bounds.width,38))
            }
            headerView!.delegate = self

            if isExpandableCell {

                headerView!.arrowImage.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

            }else {

                headerView!.arrowImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI))

            }
            return headerView

        }

        return nil
    }
```

I have a button on the custom view that I have added on the tableview section. Now how will I get the indexPath when I click on it?

Comment: only TableView cells have an index path. But there is probably a realistic way to get the section number that the header belongs to.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a section number variable in CustomHeader class and assign its value while instantiating inside viewForHeaderInSection().

Implement the target button action inside the same class. So, on tap get self.section and pass it to ViewController.

```
void onButtonTap (id sender)
        {
            UIButton button = (UIButton)sender;

        this.sectionHeaderViewDelegate.buttonTapped (this.section);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

On your function you can add a tag id to the button to be the same as the indexPath

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FoldingCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! myTableViewCell
...
cell.myButton.tag = indexPath.row
...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can assign the `tag` property of your section header view to number of section inside `tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int)` method.

Comment: But I'm initializing my headerView only once. So if I assign a tag it'll get modified so I won't be able to check through it.

Comment: So you have only one header in table view?